# PHP redirect with final URL as a parameter

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to send traffic to my site, then have it redirect to a domain that is specified in the campaign's URL. What I've tried so far is this php on a directory "redirect" within my site:

I would like to send the traffic to this URL, where the redirect takes it to the sample domain:

http://www.example.com/redirect?link="http://www.sampledomain.com"

```
<?php
// accepts a url as a query argument, checks to be sure request came from 
site
//

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ) die('not authorized');

$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$referer = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if ($referer[2] != $host) die('not authorized (2)');

$transfer = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'link', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );

header('location: ' . $transfer);
exit();
?>
```

With this method I keep getting a 403 error. Please help with any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: the redirect link will need to be encoded then decode `urlencode()`

Comment: I actually realized that I was blocking redirects that weren't coming from the original domain, and since I plan on sending paid AdWords and Bing traffic through, it was giving the not authorized. I have changed up the code to the following, but still getting the 403 error: <?php
$lines = file('./okdomains',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$transfer = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'link', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );

$http = str_replace(array('http://','https://'),'', $transfer);
$parts = explode("/",$http);

if (in_array($parts[0],$lines)) header('location: ' . $transfer);
exit('Not authorised');
?>